# Using beautifulSoup, trying to get all table rows that have a string in them

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I need to get all table rows on a page that contain a specific string 'abc123123' in them.

The string is inside a TD, but I need the entire TR if it contains the 'abc123123' anywhere inside.

I tried this:

```
userrows = s.findAll('tr', contents = re.compile('abc123123'))
```

I'm not sure if contents is the write property.

My html looks something like:

```
<tr>
   <td>
   </td>
   <td><table>.... abc123123 </table><tr>
   ..
</tr>
<tr>
..
</tr>
..
..
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the extra keyword arguments beyond the specified ones (`name, attrs, recursive, text, limit`) all refer to *attributes* of the tag you're searching for.

You cannot search for `name` *and* `text` at the same time (if you specify `text`, BS ignores `name`) so you need separate calls, e.g:

```
allrows = s.findAll('tr')
userrows = [t for t in allrows if t.findAll(text=re.compile('abc123123'))]
```

Here I'm using a list comprehension since I assume you want a list of the relevant tag objects, as `findAll` itself gives you.

Comment: or I could just do if not t.findAll(..) continue   thanks, trying it now!

Comment: ok it doesn't work, because the text i'm looking for is actually inside a href tag...hmm

Comment: @Blankman, there is no `href` tag in HTML, I guess you mean the href attribute of an `a` tag. In that case, in the second statement use `t.findall('a', href=re.compile('abc123123'))`, of course.